# Is it possible using jQuery to change the value of `table data` when an `option` is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html-table, html-select

Below I have a simple `table` with `data`, I also have two `select options`.

```
<table>
    <td class="td1" id="1">2</td>
    <td class="td2" id="2">0</td>
</table>

<select name="options" id="select">
    <option value="0" id="1a">None(do nothing)</option>
    <option value="2" id="2a">Add 2 to td1 with id 1</option>
    <option value="4" id="3a">Add 4 to td1 with id 1</option>
    <option value="2" id="4a">Add 2 to td2 with id 2</option>
    <option value="4" id="5a">Add 4 to td2 with id 2</option>
</select>

<select name="options2" id="select2">
    <option value="0" id="1b">None(do nothing)</option>
    <option value="2" id="2b">Add 2 to td1 with id 1</option>
    <option value="4" id="3b">Add 4 to td1 with id 1</option>
    <option value="2" id="4b">Add 2 to td2 with id 2</option>
    <option value="4" id="5b">Add 4 to td2 with id 2</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible using jQuery to change the value of `table data` when an `option` is selected? For example when the first `select option`, `<option value="2" id="2a">Add 2 to td1 with id 1</option>` is selected, the new value should be 4. If it is no longer selected, the value should return back to 2.

Secondly if in the fist `select option`, `<option value="2" id="2a">Add 2 to td1 with id 1</option>` is selected and in the second `select option`, `<option value="4" id="3b">Add 4 to td1 with id 1</option>` is selected, the new value should be 8, and if no longer selected should go back to 4.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Of course it's possible. JavaScript can change anything in the DOM.

Comment: `document.getElementById("1").innerText = whatever you want to change it to;`

Comment: Is there something specific you don't understand about how to implement this? Do you know how to write an event listener that runs when you choose something from a `<selecct>`?

Comment: @Barmar thank you for offering me your assistance, but this would be hard coding the `td`? Is it possible for example to do the following: `document.getElementById("1").innerText = (curent value) + 2;`

Comment: `document.getElementById("1").innerText = parseInt(document.getElementById("1").innerText ) + 2;`

Comment: If you want to be able to set it back to the original value when the user selects `None`, you should save that somewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this. I have simplified the example to allow me to ask the question. What I required this for however I have 16 `<select>`'s and  5 different `<td>` that can be changed. and the issue is any one of the `<select>`'s can change any one of the 5 `<td>` (one at a time) depending on which one is selected. Is there an alternative way to go about this that you could recommend?

Comment: You can add an attribute like `data-td-id="XXX"` to each `<select>`. Then you can use a common event listener for all of them, which can use `this.dataset.tdId` to get that value, and use that in the `getElementById()` call to know which TD to update.

Comment: I'm trying to give you general hints about how to think about this, not write the code for you.

Comment: I appreciate your assistance, when I search my question regarding this problem most of the answers relate to dynamically adding table rows and so forth. So I now have a starting point.